# League\Flysystem\FileExistsException File already exists at path:

Tags: php, database, laravel, image

All my multiple data is successfully inserted into the database. However, if I want to insert the same image as the one that has been inserted before, those errors appeared `League\Flysystem\FileExistsException File already exists at path: public/complaint/walls defect 1.jpg`. Supposedly I want the same file of image can be inserted multiple times. May I know how can I fix this?

**complaints table**

```
id
defect_id
image
description
report_by
```

**ComplaintController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Validator;
use Response;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Complaint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;

class ComplaintController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('buyers.complaint');
    }

    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        if (count($request->defect_id) > 0) {
            foreach($request->defect_id as $item=>$v) {
                if (isset($request->image[$item])) {
                    $images = $request->file('image');
                    $image_resize = Image::make($images[$item]->getRealPath());
                    $image_resize->resize(900, 630);
                    $filename = $images[$item]->getClientOriginalName();

                    Storage::put($filename, $image_resize);
                    Storage::move($filename, 'public/complaint/' . $filename);                  
                }
                $data = array(
                    'defect_id' => $request->defect_id[$item],
                    'image' => $filename,
                    'description' => $request->description[$item],
                    'report_by' => auth()->user()->typable->buyer_id,
                    'created_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
                    'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()
                );

                Complaint::insert($data);
            }
        }
        return redirect('/report-form')->with('success','Your report is submitted!');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with the DB, but you are trying to store a different image (from different request, might be the same image) with a same file name. This file already exists in your Storage location.
You either first have to check if the file already exists in the Storage location and if it does, delete it and move the new one again.
Or what I usually do is to add a random 5 character string at the end to make sure they will never have the same filename, and I save this new name to the DB.

```
$filename = \Str::random(5) . '_' . $filename;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save existing image to your directory.

Here is my sample code. I used to random image name before I save into database.

```
 trait UploadFileTrait
{
    /**
     * Upload file
     *
     * @param null $folder
     * @param null $disk
     * @param null $filename
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function uploadFile($folder = null, $disk = null, $filename = null)
    {
        $image = Image::make($filename);
        $extension = $filename->extension();
        $file = Str::random(40) . '.' . $extension;
        Storage::put($folder . $file, $image->orientate()->encode($extension), 'public');
        $image->resize(350, 350, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
            $constraint->upsize();
        })->save();

        return $file;
    }
```